# Is cpoll_cppsp framework type-safe as Ur/Web?

Tags: c++, web, frameworks, type-safety

Looking at this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856961/1793629) I assume that Ur/Web is quite safe platform.

Now looking at this benchmark (http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r9&hw=peak&test=json) I see that cpoll_cppsp framework is in most use cases 1st or in top 5.

Example code from (http://xa.us.to/cppsp/documentation.cppsp) is

```
<%#
#include <vector>
#include <string>
vector<string> hello() {
return {"hello", "world", "!"};
}
%>
<html>
<body>
    <table>
        auto a = hello();
        for(int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            %>
            <tr>
                <td><%=a[i] %></td>
            </tr>
            <%
        }
        %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Documentation is rather poor, so maybe someone could explain is this thing type-safe and has similar features(listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856961/1793629) as Ur/Web?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cppsp parse language is c++, it is not type safe (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_safety#C.2B.2B_Examples).

Crashs may occur due to invalid pointers.

Every feature listed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2856961/1793629 can be broken by badly written c++ code.

Comment: "Since cppsp parse language is c++, it is not type safe"
How people have voted this answer, even the reference you've linked says "if used incorrectly".....voluntarily hitting your head against wall and saying walls are not safe isn't a good argument.